# Angularjs - how to shuffle the class names using the scope function?

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 elements, which shows by conditional. on click of them using the 'ng-class' I am showing or hiding the element.

here is the HTML :

```
<div class="userOptions">
        <div class="row designOption" ng-class="{'active':proDesign}">
            <span ng-click="categories('proDesign')" class="icon iconD">D</span>
            <span class="info infoD">Design</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row suplyOption" ng-class="{'active':Supply}">
            <span ng-click="categories('proSupply')" class="icon iconS">S</span>
            <span class="info infoS">Supply</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row constOption" ng-class="{'active':Construct}">
            <span ng-click="categories('proConstruct')" class="icon iconC">C</span>
            <span class="info infoC">Construction</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But using the `scope` function I am not able to shuffle the class name `active`. here is my try:

```
$scope.proDesign = false;
            $scope.proConstruct = false;
            $scope.proSupply = false;

            $scope.categories = function (categ) {

                $scope.proDesign = false; //all are false.
                $scope.proConstruct = false;
                $scope.proSupply = false;

                $scope[categ] = !$scope[categ]; //became true
            }
```

But this is not working. if so, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you're using `ng-class` just to show/hide elements, why don't you use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead?

Comment: I am using some of animations using the css. so i decide to shuffle the class name

Comment: Well, check your code, you seem to have some mistakes with the variables names.

Comment: What is wrong here? can you highlight me please? - post as a answer to agree.

Comment: For instance `ng-class="{'active':Supply}"`, while in your controller it's `$scope.proSupply`. The same with `$scope.proConstruct`. It would also be helpful if you would make a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, understand thanks. can you post this as answer?

Comment: If you are using animations, `ng-if` supports them right out of the box, just include `ngAnimate` in your main module. and include the script in your page